After upgrading to Expo SDK 52, my project have some error about reactFabric-dev.js
Since upgrading to SDK 52, clicking the button no longer displays the expected interface. Instead, I get the following error:

(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: Exception in HostFunction:
Non-whitespace character found after end of conversion: "%"
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Empty
input string

These errors have the same call stack at ReactFabric.js.
Please give me some suggestions!

use command
npx expo install --fix
or use
expo-doctor
also try setting newarchenabled to false if not working
Hope it will remove errors but not sure about interface (i'm having problem with textinputs and touchableopacity (only ui wise))

"expo": {
"name": "aquatic",
"slug": "aquatic",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "landscape",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"newArchEnabled": false,
"splash": {
"image": "./assets/splash.png",
"resizeMode": "contain",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},

I tried to use npx expo install --fix & expo-doctor，but not improvement。
I also tried setting newarchenabled to false，But it can't be disabled...
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled

Try searching for empty string {" "} and remove it.
or removing some dependencies and installing one by one with correct version.

This works for me,
Once start the application check for the warning message prompt on the console. Follow the dependency version and compatible packages. once done with that re-verity by running it again till there is no dependency warning appears. make sure to delete the node_module/package-lock.json during the installation to avoid conflict package version.

I jump of this error to another by the comand:
npm instal react-native@0.76.2 --force

In sdk version 52 some arts of styles like fontSize are not supporting values like '10%' or '32em'. If you go with values like 10 and 32, it will work.
